# Django not finding the static files

Tags: django, python-venv

I am creating django project so root directory doesn't have any static folder i have two static folder in two app admin_panel and project respectively but when i run python manage.py collectstatic its shows file or folder not found:

Note: virtualenv is a project folder not venv environment

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tbosss/Desktop/environment/virtualenv/myproject/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

('admin_panel', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'admin_panel', 'static')),
('project', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project', 'static')),
```

)

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static'
```

i dont know what will be the value of static root because there two static folder inside my apps not at root location

Comment: what is the value of `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: What is `BASE_DIR` value? What is `STATIC_ROOT` value? Am I correct that your project directory is located inside `virtualenv` folder? Why?

Comment: Note, you don' t need to list your apps `static` subfolders in `STATICFILES_DIRS` - those will be detected automatically. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is for _additional_ locations.

Comment: virtualenv is folder name not vnev environment

Comment: Try specifying absolute path for STATIC_ROOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the **BASE_DIR** in **settings.py** points to your project base directory:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Now, based on your **FileNotFoundError** the static folder directory should be in the project base directory. So, the **STATIC_ROOT** should be:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: I don't have any static folder in project root directory and I want to load only my app static folder

Comment: When you run **collectstatic**, it collects static files from the directories listed in **STATICFILES_DIRS** and put them in **STATIC_ROOT** directory. STATIC_ROOT directory is automatically created. Then Django serves those static files from STATIC_ROOT directory.